# Pygame image mouse click renders image badly

Tags: python, mouseevent, pygame

I'm making a simple start button. If the user clicks the button, it will update the button image to another image (a slightly different image).  I reload the image within the Button class I wrote.  I'm not sure if that's the best way to do it, but it seems to be working except for when the image changes it is rendered terribly.  It should go from here:

[image]

To (after clicking...`MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`):

[image]

It's a slight (and crummy) change, but it should give the idea its being clicked to the user.  However, after clicking, I'm getting the following:

[image]

I'm not sure why the image become so broken, and the second image doesn't display.  Here is the code for the image loading:

```
import pygame,os,sys,math
from pygame.locals import *
import random

if not pygame.font: print 'Warning, fonts disabled'
if not pygame.mixer: print 'Warning, sound disabled'


#seperate this into a utility class
def load_image(name, colorkey=None):
    fullname = os.path.join('data', name)
    try:
        image = pygame.image.load(fullname)
    except pygame.error, message:
        print 'Cannot load image:', name
        raise SystemExit, message
    image = image.convert()
    if colorkey is not None:
        if colorkey is -1:
            colorkey = image.get_at((0,0))
        image.set_colorkey(colorkey, RLEACCEL)
    return image, image.get_rect()
```

Here are the mouse and button objects:

```
#seperate this into an object class
class Mouse(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """moves a hand on the screen, following the computer mouse"""
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) #call Sprite initializer
        self.clicking = 0
        self.image, self.rect = load_image('game_mouse.jpg', -1)

    def update(self):
        "move the hand based on the computer mouse position"
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.rect.midtop = pos
        if self.clicking:
            self.rect.move_ip(5, 10)

    def click(self, target):
        "returns true if the hand collides with the target"
        if not self.clicking:
            self.clicking = 1
            hitbox = self.rect.inflate(-5, -5)
            return hitbox.colliderect(target.rect)

    def unclick(self):
        self.clicking = 0


#seperate this into an object/menu class
class Button(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """Button class used for all menus.  Handles events"""
    def __init__(self, original_image_source, clicked_image_source, location_coordinates):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) #call Sprite intializer
        self.original_image_source = original_image_source
        self.clicked_image_source = clicked_image_source
        self.location_coordinates = location_coordinates
        self.clicked = 0
        self.image, self.rect = load_image(original_image_source, -1)
        #screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
        #self.area = screen.get_rect()
        self.rect.midtop = location_coordinates

    def update(self):
        "update on click or unclick"
        if self.clicked:
            self.image, self.rect = load_image(self.clicked_image_source, -1)
            self.rect.midtop = self.location_coordinates
        else:
            self.image, self.rect = load_image(self.original_image_source, -1)
            self.rect.midtop = self.location_coordinates

    def set_clicked(self):
        self.clicked = 1

    def set_unclicked(self):
        self.clicked = 0
```

Here is the main method:

```
def main():

    # Initialise screen
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 600))
    pygame.display.set_caption('States of Matter')
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)

    background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
    background = background.convert()
    background.fill((250, 250, 250))

    #elements_background = load_image("4-elements-background.jpg")
    #background.blit(elements_background[0],(-450, -200))

    if pygame.font:
        font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
        text = font.render("States of Matter", 1, (10, 10, 10))
        textpos = text.get_rect(centerx=background.get_width()/2)
        background.blit(text, textpos)


    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()

    mouse = Mouse()
    start_button = Button("start_button_original.jpg", "start_button_clicked.jpg", (background.get_width()/2,background.get_height()/3))
    all_sprites = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain((mouse, start_button))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    #game driver
    while 1:
        clock.tick(60)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                return
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                return
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if mouse.click(start_button):
                    start_button.set_clicked()
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                mouse.unclick()
                start_button.set_unclicked()

        all_sprites.update()

        #redraw everything
        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

I want it so it can update to the other image after being clicked (and back to the original image when the mouse click is released).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the following:

```
self.image, self.rect = load_image(self.clicked_image_source, -1)
```

When I loaded my images, I passed -1 for ***color key***.  I should be passing `None`.  This goes for all the mouse and button images I use.  Since I use `.JPG` images, I get an issue relating to the ***artifacts*** stored inside `.JPG` images.